# Glitchy effect when I hover from the bottom of my box

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a box which expands on hover and show products, I created it but when I hover on it from the bottom side hover animation does some glitchy effect and if only the image come out of it. I made this effect using gsap in side the eventListener of mouseenter and mouseleave, so can you  guys take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong and how should I fix it.

Here's the snipper you guy's can check it out if needed.

```js
function page2boxhover() {
  // box1 hover in box content
  var box = document.querySelector("#box1");
  box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    gsap.to(box, {
      height: "300px",
      duration: 0.2,
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#box1 img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 1;
      e.style.scale = 1;
    });
  });

  box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    gsap.to(box, {
      height: "60px",
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#page2 .elem .box .boxContent img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 0;
      e.style.scale = 0;
    });
  });

  // box2 hover in box context
  var box2 = document.querySelector("#box2");
  box2.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    gsap.to(box2, {
      height: "300px",
      duration: 0.2,
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#box2 .boxContent img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 1;
      e.style.scale = 1;
    });
  });

  box2.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    gsap.to(box2, {
      height: "60px",
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#box2 img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 0;
      e.style.scale = 0;
    });
  });

  //box3 hover in box content
  var box3 = document.querySelector("#box3");
  box3.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    gsap.to(box3, {
      height: "300px",
      duration: 0.2,
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#box3 .boxContent img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 1;
      e.style.scale = 1;
    });
  });

  box3.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    gsap.to(box3, {
      height: "60px",
    });
    var img = document.querySelectorAll("#box3 img");
    img.forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.opacity = 0;
      e.style.scale = 0;
    });
  });
}
page2boxhover();
```

```css
#page2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3vw 2vw;
  position: relative;
}

#page2 .elem {
  height: 100%;
  width: 31%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#page2 .elem img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  scale: 1.1;
}

.elem .box {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c1aaa3;
}

.elem .box .boxHead {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.boxHead h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.boxHead h5:nth-child(3) {
  font-weight: 600;
}

#page2 .elem .box .boxContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#page2 .elem .box .boxContent img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Two Good Co</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon-32x32.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@3.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="page2">
            <div id="elem1" class="elem">
                <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1"
                    src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/f445a3d15e318fd217579e88ec2c6d0140246403-3574x4467.jpg/DSC0078_Dexter%20Kim.jpg?rect=448,0,2679,4467&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format"
                    alt="">
                <div style="background-color: #C3D8C5;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box1" class="box">
                    <div class="boxHead">
                        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
                        <h5>SHOP</h5>
                        <h5>HOME</h5>
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxContent">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/7a2007de38624a0b2935416bf51a4584889aa232-5000x5000.png/Website%20Products%20(12).png?w=1024&h=1024&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/7d180ca25ade6277a215b634318056d551de9da8-5000x5000.png/Website%20Products%20(5).png?w=320&h=320&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="elem2" class="elem">
                <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1"
                    src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/90d06c39f74f1365c801ec2a063227969c5ef940-2560x3840.jpg/LucyTweed_Photo:KatieKarrs.jpg?rect=129,0,2303,3840&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format"
                    alt="">
                <div style="background-color: #F2DCCB;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box2" class="box">
                    <div class="boxHead">
                        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
                        <h5>SHOP</h5>
                        <h5>PANTRY</h5>
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxContent">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/ff380ebfee344ff98d24d4156ded6b9dc22a2a2a-5000x5000.png/Change-The-Course-Cookbook-Two-Good-Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/4206e9c3f7ab098369c39a2194b82eeca6bb0664-6166x4111.png/DSC0005_Dexter%20Kim.png?rect=0,4,6166,4104&w=320&h=213&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="elem3" class="elem">
                <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1"
                    src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/d3151106849ff2494d66916cf554c68a0603444d-902x1500.png/Rectangle%20220.png?rect=1,0,900,1500&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format"
                    alt="">
                <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box3" class="box">
                    <div class="boxHead">
                        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
                        <h5>SHOP</h5>
                        <h5>BATH</h5>
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxContent">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/63474079ab0c7723b75bd63b24d8bbc652349640-1408x1408.png/Cleanse%20&%20Nourish%20Hand%20Wash%20Two%20Good%20Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/99866b12faf44f7490e6037dc197947334ce0a72-1408x1408.png/Nourish%20&%20Soothe%20Hand%20Lotion%20Two%20Good%20Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/locomotive-scroll@3.5.4/dist/locomotive-scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-16esztaSRplJROstbIIdwX3N97V1+pZvV33ABoG1H2OyTttBxEGkTsoIVsiP1iaTtM8b3+hu2kB6pQ4Clr5yug=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-Ic9xkERjyZ1xgJ5svx3y0u3xrvfT/uPkV99LBwe68xjy/mGtO+4eURHZBW2xW4SZbFrF1Tf090XqB+EVgXnVjw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.elem .box { overflow: hidden; }`?

Answer (score 0):

So i just organized the code and removed the gsap usage so the animation is made using plain CSS and it seems to fix it.

The flickering happens because `boxContent` and `boxHead`  are still there and the mouse can still interact with them even if they are not visible.

Adding `pointer-events: none` to their CSS fixed the flickering.
A clever fix is adding `overflow: hidden` to the `box` element as you said.

A usefull tool to use in these cases is the browser's developer tools specifically the [Inspect Element Tool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chrome-inspect-element-tool-shortcut/).

```js
function page2boxhover() {
  const toggleBox = (el, bool) => el.classList.toggle("mouseEnter", bool);

  [...document.querySelectorAll(".box")].forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => toggleBox(box, true));
    box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => toggleBox(box, false));
  })
}
page2boxhover();
```

```css
/* Added CSS code to the bottom of this! */

#page2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3vw 2vw;
  position: relative;
}

#page2 .elem {
  height: 100%;
  width: 31%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#page2 .elem img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  scale: 1.1;
}

.elem .box {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c1aaa3;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.elem .box .boxHead {
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.boxHead h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.boxHead h5:nth-child(3) {
  font-weight: 600;
}

#page2 .elem .box .boxContent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

#page2 .elem .box .boxContent img {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}


/* let css handle the animation */

.box {
  transition: height .7s;
}

.box.mouseEnter {
  height: 300px;
  transition: height .2s !important;
}

.box.mouseEnter .boxContent img {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  scale: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="page2">
  <div id="elem1" class="elem">
    <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1" src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/f445a3d15e318fd217579e88ec2c6d0140246403-3574x4467.jpg/DSC0078_Dexter%20Kim.jpg?rect=448,0,2679,4467&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format" alt="">
    <div style="background-color: #C3D8C5;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box1" class="box">
      <div class="boxHead">
        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
        <h5>SHOP</h5>
        <h5>HOME</h5>
        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="boxContent">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/7a2007de38624a0b2935416bf51a4584889aa232-5000x5000.png/Website%20Products%20(12).png?w=1024&h=1024&auto=format" alt="">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/7d180ca25ade6277a215b634318056d551de9da8-5000x5000.png/Website%20Products%20(5).png?w=320&h=320&auto=format" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="elem2" class="elem">
    <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1" src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/90d06c39f74f1365c801ec2a063227969c5ef940-2560x3840.jpg/LucyTweed_Photo:KatieKarrs.jpg?rect=129,0,2303,3840&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format" alt="">
    <div style="background-color: #F2DCCB;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box2" class="box">
      <div class="boxHead">
        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
        <h5>SHOP</h5>
        <h5>PANTRY</h5>
        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="boxContent">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/ff380ebfee344ff98d24d4156ded6b9dc22a2a2a-5000x5000.png/Change-The-Course-Cookbook-Two-Good-Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format" alt="">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/4206e9c3f7ab098369c39a2194b82eeca6bb0664-6166x4111.png/DSC0005_Dexter%20Kim.png?rect=0,4,6166,4104&w=320&h=213&auto=format" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div id="elem3" class="elem">
    <img data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1" src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/d3151106849ff2494d66916cf554c68a0603444d-902x1500.png/Rectangle%20220.png?rect=1,0,900,1500&w=640&h=1067&fit=min&auto=format" alt="">
    <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" data-scroll data-scroll-speed="-1" id="box3" class="box">
      <div class="boxHead">
        <i class="ri-add-line"></i>
        <h5>SHOP</h5>
        <h5>BATH</h5>
        <i class="ri-arrow-right-s-line"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="boxContent">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/63474079ab0c7723b75bd63b24d8bbc652349640-1408x1408.png/Cleanse%20&%20Nourish%20Hand%20Wash%20Two%20Good%20Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format" alt="">
        <img src="https://cdn.sanity.io/images/w8f1ak3c/production/99866b12faf44f7490e6037dc197947334ce0a72-1408x1408.png/Nourish%20&%20Soothe%20Hand%20Lotion%20Two%20Good%20Co.png?w=320&h=320&auto=format" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if there was no glitch in the animation, doing stuff with plain HTML / CSS as far as possible is always the best solution.

Comment: its still giving that glitch effect from bottom and I will try to make it in CSS from now on.

Comment: The glitch you're talking about is that flickering that happens when the box changes size? That happens because `boxContent` is still there and the mouse can interact with it even if it is not visible

Comment: I added `pointer-events: none` to it's style and it fixed the flickering.

Comment: @LuísHenriquedeAlmeida yes I fixed it by using `over-flow: hidden`

Comment: i edited the answer, could you upvote and mark it as correct? :)